# Repeatedly perform a transaction on polygon network every 'x' minutes

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to make a similar transaction every few minutes/hours on the polygon network

I have already created the front end for time selection and replicating a transaction, the only thing I need to know is how can I call a particular function of a smart contract every few minutes/hours without making the user approve the transaction every time (basically automate repeated function calls), there was a solution called Ethereum Alarm Clock but it won't work on polygon. So is there anything I can do?

Comment: that is working with other network ?

Comment: @MERN it is supposed to, I have seen examples online but its based on ethereum with its own time nodes and incentives (its website is down tho, it might be dead I'm not sure), I don't think it works with polygon